# Difference between dask distributed wait(future) vs future.result()?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

For waiting from future completion in Dask distributed cluster, what's the difference between these two APIs? Are there any?

wait: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#waiting-on-futures

result(): tttps://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Future.result

If there's any difference, what would be the more efficient way to block until result is available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`wait` blocks further execution until the futures are completed, and once they are, the code proceeds. `result` transfers the result of the future from the worker to the client computer. In most cases, it’s probably more efficient to leave `future` with workers until the client needs them.

For example, imagine that you are coordinating calculations using a small laptop with 10GB ram which is connected to a cluster that has workers with memory of 50GB each. If the data you are processing is around 20GB, then the workers will have no problem doing calculations, however if you try to use `.result()` with the intention to just wait for execution to complete, then the workers will try to send to you 20GB of data each, which will crash your laptop session.